# font garamond do not compile

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I would like to use the mathfont \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}  but it does not compile with PDFLatex.

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    $\mathcal{W} \ell~\mathcal{E}~$$\mathcal{C}$ et $\mathscr{C}~q$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    $  \left( \overrightarrow{u}+\overrightarrow{v}\right) +\overrightarrow{w}= \left( \overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}\right) +\overrightarrow{CD}=\overrightarrow{AC}+\overrightarrow{CD} = \bm{\overrightarrow{AD}} $
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    $ v+x+y-z+\Delta+\sum\Rightarrow \Leftrightarrow+\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta+\epsilon+\varepsilon+\lambda+\nu+\omega+\Delta+\rho-\mu $
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    $ \bm{\sqrt{x} }\int~~~\mathscr{L}~~~ \mathcal{R}$
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It compiles for me with TeX Live 2020. What error message do you get?

Comment: i use TeXstudio and th error is in french : Processus terminé avec une ou plusieurs erreurs

Comment: Check the `.log` file and make sure you have all the packages installed that you’re using.

Comment: i got this errors :


Package mathdesign/mdugm Warning: Package 'mathrsfs' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdugm, on input line 15.


Package mathdesign/mdugm Warning: Package 'amssymb' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdugm, on input line 15.


Package mathdesign/mdugm Warning: Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdugm, on input line 15.

Comment: I deleted the packages but i have this error :                                                                                                                                                                                                            ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

Comment: There should be a more complete error message saying what the error was, and on which line. But make sure that you have an up-to-date TeX distribution with those packages installed.

Comment: I update TeX distribution but the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, that’s not enough information to solve the problem. If you check the console output and the `.log` file, there should be a message saying what the fatal error was.